# перевод числа в ассемблер TASM

Tags: ассемблер, tasm

Помогите с функцией перевода числа в строку, не понимаю как это происходит.
Знаю что есть buff dw 2 dup(' '), count db 12
и как мне число count записать в строку buff.

```
    .model small
    .stack 100h
    .data
a   dw  12
b   dw  10
buff    dw  5 dup(' ')
    .code
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax
    mov si,offset buff
    mov ax,a
    mov     bx,b
    idiv    bx
    push    dx
    idiv    bx
    push    dx
    pop ax
    add ax,30h
    mov buff[si-1],ax
    pop ax
    add ax,30h
    mov buff[si],ax
    mov dx,offset buff
    mov ah,9
    int     21h 
    mov ax,4c00h
    int 21h
    end
```

Comment: сначала определитесь с тем в какой системе счисления должно быть число в виде строки. потом ищите функцию перевода системы счисления. Обычный путь - деление числа на основание системы счисления и запись остатков от деления, преобразованных в символы, в строку

Comment: @Mike ну 10 система счисления, я написал примитивную функцию, но она записывает только 1 цифру, и почему то когда 1/10 получаю 3 в остатке а должна быть единица, в чём проблема?

Comment: Сложно сказать в чем проблема, не видя код

Comment: @Mike добавил проверь пожалуйста

Comment: Вы делите на bx, двубайтное значение, при этом делимое находится в dx:ax, И при этом в регистре dx у вас неизвестно что, поэтому результат деления не предсказуем. очищайте dx перед делением или делите на байт (bl например), остаток в этом случае будет в AH. и один символ это байт, не правильно в буфер писать по 2 байта (ax) (если конечно вы заранее в ax не сформируете полное значение обоих символов. А еще функция 9 печатает строку до знака `$`, стоит заносить его в целевую строку, а то будет печать черти что